# How does synching with the Ubuntu Keyservers work? (Seahorse)

Tags: sync, seahorse

I'm trying to import keys from Ubuntu Keyservers via Seahorse. I gon into Remote --> Find remote keys Look for the key and then Click on Synch and Publish

[image: Seahorse synch dialog]

I click on synch and still don't get the keys from the keyserver.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import keys, you will instead need to select the **Remote** > **Find Remote Keys...** option, which looks like this:

[image: Searching for an email address that you can't see!]

Enter the desired search string (usually an e-mail address or fingerprint) and then click <kbd>Search</kbd>. You will then be shown a list of keys:

[image: A redacted list of PGP keys]

From there, select the key you want to import (making sure to inspect the key first to make sure the fingerprint is correct!). Then, hit **Import** to grab the keys.

If you don't see the keys immediately, it's likely you're hiding keys you don't control. To show all keys your system is aware of (and not just keys you control), go to the **View** menu item and select **Show any**.

You, instead, synchronized your private keys. By doing this, you [published your key records to keyservers](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x457.html). By doing this, you have just made your public PGP key much easier to find in the wild, as anyone can now search for your key by e-mail, fingerprint, or other methods.

Once you publish a key, [you can not take it back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_(cryptographic)). Keyservers will exchange keys (and others will download keys) to decentralize the system so that one keyserver being compromised or taken down does not break PGP. These keyservers will also handle key trust, and will carry records of PGP key signatures made by other people.

Comment: Ok, and is Seahorse supposed to show this grabbed keys?

Comment: Yes. If it doesn't, you may be filtering by only keys you control (have the private key for). In the menu, go to **View** and select **Show any** to see all keys you have in your keyring.

Comment: Please add that to the answer